# Excel 2013 to 2010 backward compatibility issue with ActiveX (NOT Dec14th update issue)

Tags: vba, excel, activex

I am transitioning a set of interrelated Excel documents that use VBA code for lookups, data manipulation and calculations from Excel 2010 to Excel 365.  I have both on my development machine, however these get sent (via email) to customers all over and then returned.  I use .xlmb file formats for the file size savings however this doesn't seem to be affecting the outcome.

CURRENT ISSUE
When I save a workbook using 365 on my development machine, users get errors when performing an action that runs my VBA code when run from a machine that only has 2010 installed (if both versions are installed, the behavior does not seem to happen).  I have focused the problem to when there is code in a module and there is an ActiveX control on a sheet.  ONLY this combination seems to create the issue.

The test file/code I've created that consistently shows the issue is a workbook with the following code in a module:

```
Dim strBook As String
' Worksheet Names
Public Const wksTest = "Sheet1"

Public Function TestMe(PassedSheet As String)

    strBook = ActiveWorkbook.Name

    Workbooks(strBook).Worksheets(PassedSheet).Protect
    Workbooks(strBook).Worksheets(PassedSheet).Unprotect

    MsgBox "Worked from function", vbOKOnly, "Response"

End Function
```

And code in the sheet.  It works with this code and selecting cell B2 protects and then unprotects the sheet while displaying message boxes:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Row = 2 And Target.Column = 2 Then

        strBook = ActiveWorkbook.Name

        Me.Protect
        Me.Unprotect

        MsgBox "Worked from sheet", vbOKOnly, "Response"

        Call TestMe(wksTest)

    End If

End Sub
```

However if an ActiveX Command Button named "TestButton" is added to Sheet1 and this code is added:

```
Private Sub TestButton_Click()

    strBook = ActiveWorkbook.Name

    Me.Protect
    Me.Unprotect

    MsgBox "Worked from Button", vbOKOnly, "Response"

    Call TestMe(wksTest)

End Sub
```

The workbook will no longer function if saved from 365 and opened with 2010 on a machine with only 2010 installed.

This is unique enough that it has been difficult to test.  Currently, the only option I seem to have is replace all my command buttons with Form Controls.  This also is a separate issue from the security update (which is really muddying the waters).
I would love to get feedback on possible fixes for this issue or even just confirmation from others that this is an Excel issue and not somehow limited to our installation.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for help on a similar question and stumbled on this info on the Microsoft help site. If this doesn't solve the problem you have, it might be a step in the right direction:

"If a workbook contains ActiveX controls that are considered to be Unsafe for Initialization (UFI), they are lost when you save the workbook to an earlier Excel file format. You may want to mark those controls as Safe for Initialization (SFI).

What to do: If you open a workbook that contains uninitialized ActiveX controls, and the workbook is set to high security, you must first use the Message Bar to enable them before they can be initialized."